# No scrolling/paging of entries in Name Picker (Ext.Lib)

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

When using the Ext.Lib Name Picker control connected to the NAB, the default is to view the first 50 entries from selected view (depending on whether groups/Persons is selected in property). 
But there are no scroll/paging buttons on the dialog.

If I want to pick an entry from the NABPicker and the entry is after the first 50 I must use the Search button to find it.

Is this working as designed or a feature not yet added?

/Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is working as designed. The server only returns a set number of entries so that the amount of data transfered when opening the Name Picker dialog box is kept nice and small, this way the dialog box opens faster.

You can increase the number of entries returned by increasing the maximum limits in the server document and internet site document and then increasing the maxRowCount attribute on the picker but you will seriously affect the performance of your application and it is not recommended.

Hopefully in a future release of the control they will add some sort of ajax based scroll similar to the inbox scroll in iNotes.

Comment: This attribute is not available on the picker as far as I can see.
Has this been added in a later release than 8.5.3.20111221-0529 ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in using the viewpicklist control from openntf instead, [link](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=View%20Picklist%20Custom%20Control)
It is very felxable, just set it to use the names.nsf and whichever view you need.

Answer (score 0):

Mike:

I think the answer is "both". Working as designed and feature not added yet...

The Ext Lib is a open source initiative designed to support the simplistic Discussion, Team Room, and Document Library applications. The designers have limited experience with more complex applications and clearly limited exposure to large address books in their development arena.

The NAB pickers are a source a major disapointment to those of us trying to build larger scale applications. Perhaps at some point it will become a usable component but is is only marginally usable at this point.

/Newbs