# Xpages xe:namePicker only returns the first 50 names in the selection dialog

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using the xe:namepicker for some time and setting the source as a xe:dominoViewNamePicker as follows:

```
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker5" for="SiteAdm" dialogTitle="Add one Site Administrator">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:dominoViewNamePicker viewName="CoordinatorsByEmail"
            labelColumn="CoordEmail">
        </xe:dominoViewNamePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:namePicker>
```

The problem I am having is the returned list of names is being cut off at 50.  Users can use the search box in the dialog to start the at another point, but it is always limited to 50 names to choose from.

None of the documented properties indicate if there is a way or setting to set or remove this limitation.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35179668/206265 https://stackoverflow.com/a/9101118/206265

Comment: that fixed it, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPages ValuePicker Limited to 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179149/xpages-valuepicker-limited-to-1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks go to Frantisek for pointing me in the right direction.  The limitation applies to the xe:valuePicker and the xe:namePicker for any data provider.  The solution is to add the maxRowCount dojo attribute with your own limit:

```
            <xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="inputText1">
                <xe:this.dataProvider>
                    <xe:dominoNABNamePicker addressBookSel="all" nameList="people"></xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
                </xe:this.dataProvider>
                <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                    <xp:dojoAttribute name="maxRowCount" value="10000">
                    </xp:dojoAttribute>
                </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
            </xe:namePicker>
```